# Click separate link when menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, submenu

I am trying to have a link in the submenu of a wordpress website go to a link located somewhere else on the page when clicked.

So far this is my code

```
 <script>
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("#menu-item-6084").click(function(){
$("a.job-dashboard-action-edit").click()
    });
});
});
</script>
```

It does not throw any errors in the console, but it does not do anything when the menu item is clicked. May be worth nothing I placed javascript:void(0) as the link in the menu.

Comment: What do you mean by "go to a link located somewhere else on the page"?  Scroll up/down to that location on the page?

Comment: It might help if you explain what you're trying to do, it's pretty unclear currently.

Comment: @Ageonix I have a link on the page such as `<a href='www.link.com  class="job-dashboard-action-edit">LINK</a>` and I would like to go to this link when a menu item is clicked. Hope is this is a little clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without JS at all.

```
<a id="menu-item-6084" href="#page-bookmark">Click me</a>
...
<!-- this is where you want to go in your page -->
<div id="page-bookmark"></div>
```

**UPDATED:**

For dynamic links, you can wire them up once they are added to the DOM like so:

```
<!-- page-bookmark6084 is the target element to navigate to -->
$("#menu-item-6084").attr("href", "#page-bookmark6084");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer under the assumption that you want to scroll to another element (link) on the same page.  For this, you want JQuery's scrollTop() function.  The code below will give you a nice 1-second animation to the link (assuming a.job-dashboard-action-edit is your link...probably better to use an ID here).

```
$("#menu-item-6084").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("a.job-dashboard-action-edit").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

If you don't care about a smoothed scrolling effect, @Steve Danner's answer is the simplest way to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thank you, but instead of scrolling to the link, I would like the browser to go directly to this link. The link is dynamically generated and this is why I can't put it directly in the menu.

Comment: When you say "go to the link", do you mean navigate the user to the URL then?

Comment: As @Ageonix says, if you want the smooth animations, use his jquery above, but if you want simple navigation, use my answer, which I've updated to show how to dynamically set your href's.

Comment: @Ageonix Yes, navigate the user to the url.